# Non blocking response for azure service bus queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an Azure Service Bus with 3 different queue with different "priority" (high, medium, low). This "priority" is only represented in the naming, our workers take care of this by checking always for a new message first in the "high" queue, then "medium" and then "low".

We use the REST API for the service bus:

XX://XXX.servicebus.windows.net/{high|medium|low}/messages/head

Our problem is, if a worker checks only a single queue, then it processes the data very fast, as we would expect, but if any of the queue is empty from the 3, there is like a 5 sec "wait/blocking". Whenever we call the "messages/head" endpoint, it looks like, that the call is waiting a bit for a message to arrive into the queue.

Is there a way to disable this "blocking" and if the queue is empty, then the response is immediately sent, like if there is a message inside of it?

Comment: I don't use REST API, but when receiving a message using .NET SDK, there's a receive timeout setting. Perhaps that's exposed via REST API. What language/SDK do you use?

Comment: @ghostika Refer  [1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements.md) [2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-prefetch.md)

Comment: We use PHP, which doesn't support AMQP 1.0, only the older version, so REST API is the only way forward. As I mentioned, the only problem is if we want all of our worker to listen to every queue - which is the behaviour today.

Comment: @ghostika could you please share the code you tried

Comment: @Sampath it's nothing else as 3 URLs in an array and I iterate over them and call the API endpoint. If the first 2 are empty, it takes 10 seconds to get to the 3rd queue.